# Deployment time checklist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

If you were to create a checklist of things you needed to do before you deploy a typical Java EE webapp that makes use of servlets, ejbs, o/r mapping, relational databases, etc what would be on it? Like any sort of time out properties and settings, pool sizes, jndi related properties, etc. that are crucial at production deployment.

For instance, I just found out today that I need to make sure that I need to check that idle database connections in the connection pool need to be checked so that they dont become stale after the idle timeout period.

Comment: Nothing.  If you haven't already checked those things in QA, it is not ready to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

For me this just comes w/ experience, and can vary by application.  Just take note of what you are doing as far as jndi, and datasources in your dev env. especially if this is a new application.  And then adjust pool sizes and other attributes depending up the load expected.  For most of my applications(deployed in jboss) I use the default setting for most things, and then only tune/adjust when necessary, but this is just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would set up an acceptance or performance test environment, with some real data sizes, where these settings would be fleshed out.